# Simple Network Graph Plotting in Python?

Tags: python, graph

I am working on some algorithms that create network graphs, and I am finding it really hard to debug the output. The code is written in Python, and I am looking for the simplest way to view the resulting network.

Every node has a reference to its parent elements, but a helper function could be written to format the network in any other way.

What is the simplest way to display a network graph from Python? Even if it's not fully written in Python, ie it uses some other programs available to Linux, it would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something to help debugging the network you are constructing. For this you might want to consider implementing a function that converts your network to [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)), a graph description language, which can then be rendered to a graph visualization using a number of tools, such as [GraphViz](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz). You can then log the output from this function to help debug.

Comment: This is exactly how I sorted it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Netwulf](https://github.com/benmaier/netwulf/)? It takes a *networkx.Graph* object as input and launches an interactive d3-powered visualization in a separate browser window. The resulting image (and data) can then be posted back to Python for further processing.

[image: img]

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of Netwulf.*

Answer (score 1):

Think about using existing graph libraries for your problem domain, e.g. [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/). Drawing can be done from there with *matplotlib* or *pygraphviz*.

For bigger projects, you might also want to check out a graph database like [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com) with its toolkit (and own query language CYPHER) for working with python.

A good interface markup is also GraphML, can be useful with drawing tools like [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) in case you have small graphs and need some manual finish.